# Unity ResolveAll descendants

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have base interface `IBaseModel` with many descendants (ex. `IContactModel : IBaseModel;`, `IRelationModel : IBaseModel;` etc.) and objects what implements this interfaces.

All this descendants interfaces is registered in Unity container.

How can I resolve all my objects what is descendant from `IBaseModel`?

Comment: What about [container.ResolveAll<IBaseModel>()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee651424)? Can you post how is your container registration looks like? And one sample use where do you the all the `IBaseModel`s?

Comment: ResolveAll in this case dont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var types = Container
  .Registrations
  .Where(x => typeof (IBaseModel).IsAssignableFrom(x.RegisteredType))
  .Select(x => x.RegisteredType)
  .ToList();

var result = types
  .Select(x => (IBaseModel) Container.Resolve(x.UnderlyingSystemType))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you so much... I was looking for such a solution for a while!